# How can I create UI-less custom function Excel add-ins?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, custom-functions-excel

In the "Custom Functions' section of the Excel API documentation, there is a subsection for ["UI-less custom functions"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-authentication). However, while they talk about authentication issues, how to debug, and runtime differences, they never explicitly state how to create such a project. How is this done?

Just for the sake of clarity, I'm hoping to create an Excel add-in that provides a few custom functions but does not have a taskpane and thus (hopefully) does not require a web server to serve the corresponding html to end users. Is this within the scope of a UI-less custom function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Functions require 2 additional files regardless of any UI features (taskpane, ribbon, etc.). Those are:

1. The *Metadata* (JSON) file. Defines the function signatures.
2. Either the *Script* (JS) file or the *Page* (HTML) file. Contains the function implementations. If you have a default Runtime, *Script* will be used. If you have a Shared Runtime, *Page* will be used.

So, you will have to serve 2 additional files. Luckily, those files are static and could be served from any public location like OneDrive or GitHub.

To make your add-in, UI-less, just don't include any UI definitions for taskpane, tabs, menus, etc. in the manifest. There isn't anything special.

Comment: By the "script" file, are you referring to the file found at `./dist/functions.js` which is generated from `./src/functions/functions.js` when running `npm run build`, correct? Also, do you know of any tools similar to Yeoman which would allow me to generate a manifest which would have the bare minimum information to be used in my UI-less custom function add-in?

Comment: I am not an expert on the tools - I am a Runtime guy. However, I am sure support for custom functions is included in the Office add-ins tools. In the manifest, there is a "CustomFunctions" extension point that has a <Metadata> and a <Script> (or a <Page>) element. You can use this manifest as an example - https://github.com/OfficeDev/custom-functions/blob/master/addins/upgrade/upgrade_appcmd.xml. Put it on a file share, and you can install it from there. No tools are needed. It does contain a task pane an 2 buttons. You can remove the entire <DesktopFormFactor> element, if you don't want them.